# Undo preventDefault() after API call

Tags: javascript

I am writing external script to check availability for e-commerce store. When "Add to basket" button is pressed, I'm calling my API and checking if product is available to order. However, I don't know how to undo preventDefault(). When condition is true, event under button should continue and product should be added to basket as without the script.

```
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
fetch(`https://example.com/api.php?part=${partId}`)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (jsonRes) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonRes));
        if (jsonRes.part.partFound == true) {
            console.log('Found! Processing...');
            // REMOVE preventDefault() and process
        } else {
            console.log('Not found! Aborting...', partId);
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: if (true) { ... }

Comment: can't you just call the function that was originally bound to the button ?
or submit the form with JS if it is a form submit

Comment: Not possible to undo it. You can call something, but you can not pause that event in any way and restart it.

Comment: Do you even need the preventDefault? Perhaps just change it from a submit button (if it is one) to a type="button".

Comment: Yes - otherwise e-commerce shop script is adding product to basket + redirecting to basket subpage. I need to stop it somehow until I receive data from API.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is `type="submit" change it to`type="button"`. This

a) Won't submit the form

b) Means that you don't have to use `preventDefault` to prevent the form from submitting

That simply means you're left to decide how you want the data to be submitted, and you can either do that with another AJAX call to an API endpoint, or by submitting the whole form to the server - whichever is your setup.

```js
// Grab the form and button, and add an event
// listener to the button
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// Fake API call
function fakeAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`API called!`)
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function handleClick() {
  console.log('Clicked');
  fakeAPI(2000).then(data => {
    // If partfound submit the form data
    // Either another fetch call to post the data,
    // or `form.submit()` to post the whole form instead
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button">
    Click
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like code below:

```
async function apiCall(onSuccess, onError) {
    fetch(`https://example.com/api.php?part=${partId}`)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (jsonRes) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonRes));
            if (jsonRes.part.partFound == true) {
                console.log('Found! Processing...');
                onSuccess(jsonRes);
            } else {
                console.log('Not found! Aborting...', partId);
                onError();
            }
        });
}

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // show loading or something
    apiCall(function (response) {
        // success
    }, function () {
        // error
    });
});
```

Comment: Without preventDefault default button event is triggered.

Comment: yes, you have to move button action to the `onSuccess` callback